# Linux distros Usage share vs time graph?

Tags: linux, distributions

Here is a graph for windows usage. Is there something comparable for Linux Distros? Where all the major linux distros show up instead of one line for all linux.
[image]

I would be happy with the last 10 yrs, and 5 distros graphed for relative market share.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems

Comment: Distrowatch keeps track of some popularity, but I don't think they generate graphs: http://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=popularity

Comment: @muru They also specifically state, "They correlate neither to usage nor to quality and should not be used to measure the market share of distributions"